# usb issues on ubuntu

Tags: usb, windows, video, music

i have 2 64gb usb sticks that had all my backed up music on them. when i attached them to the laptop ubuntu said it was only 24mb and had nothing on. now when i plug into a windows laptop my stick is only 24mb and nothing else is detected. i also have 2 TB hard drives but there is no way im hooking them up until i can resolve this issues?? can anyone help as i have tried various things and various usbs and the same thing happens to them all, i essentially now have 4 unusable usb sticks and one is only a day old.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a wild guess here (because I've had it too with my first 64GB USB stick) that these sticks may need exFAT.  Try installing exFAT support first, and see what it does: `apt-get install exfat-fuse`.  Try inserting them again.

Alternatively, run the "Disks" program, and give me a screenshot of the USB disk in question.

The 2TB disk drives should not have this issue, because they will not use exFAT.  They will most likely be formatted NTFS these days.

Granted.  Wild guess based on experience, given the limited amount of information you give.

Comment: Thank you will give it a try, sorry my question was so lacking in detail was typed whilst on the move. Basically what happens is i put in my usb and it detects it however it says only 24mb available. When I click on properties it doesn't seem to register that it is a 64gb stick. When I saw there was only 24mb I thought it might be as it was full with music. However when I now insert into a Windows laptop it only registers as 24mb even if re formatted . So now I'm stuck with no music and a useless usb. This has happened to several usb that I have and it's getting really frustrating.

Comment: Ok got a slight update, I have realised that my Ian shows up if I open drives, it says it's fat32 however I am unable to access anything on it., when in command prompt and I type df -Th it didn't show up. Not going to lie this whole usb issue is really annoying me , never had this with Windows. I'm new to Ubuntu so don't understand fully m, I just want my usbs to work as I use it a lot at work but hey are a Windows system.

Comment: please see above

Comment: Do you have smaller USB keys?  Like 4GB ones, for test?
The behaviour is peculiar.
It looks like, for some reason, the partition tables of these USB sticks got broken.  Can you either show the partions on the disks (make a screenshot) under Windows using "Computer Management", or using the "Disks" or "GParted" applications on Ubuntu.

Comment: stupid question but how do add a screen shot to my comment

Comment: You can't...  Either add it to your question, or use imgur.com or similar services.

Comment: Ok I have come to the conclusion that basically I have to format everything to fat32 and get rid of all the partitions and have a brand new clean usb stick, I upgraded to 16 from 14 and it now recognises the sticks but are non accessible so need to be wiped

Comment: You can format them exFAT.  See my answer.